# Silverstripe 3.1 - BetterButtons Custom Action in DataExtension

Tags: silverstripe

Is there a way to add a custom button to the Member Object with Unclecheese BetterButtons? I'm extending the Member Object with a DataExtension where I want to create a BetterButtons Custom Action.

That's my code and the error I receive

```
private static $better_buttons_actions = array(
        'createAccountPdf'
    );

    public function getBetterButtonsActions(){
    $fields = parent::getBetterButtonsActions();

        if( $this->owner->Accounts()->Count() > 0 ){
            $fields->push(BetterButtonCustomAction::create('createAccountPdf', 'Datenblatt erstellen')->setSuccessMessage('PDF Datenblatt mit Zugangsdaten wurde erstellt.'));
        }

        return $fields;
    }
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DataObject::getBetterButtonsActions() in /_website/_dev/mysite/code/Extensions/ClientMemberExtension.php on line 128
```

Instead of parent::getBetterButtonsActions() I also tried it with $this->owner, Member::, DataObject::

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds logical cause the parent of your extension doesn't have a method called "getBetterButtonActions".

From the code in BetterButtonDataObject i see there is already a hook to update ButtonActions in a DataExtension.

try:

```
public function updateBetterButtonsActions(&$actions) {
        if( $this->owner->Accounts()->Count() > 0 ){
            $actions->push(BetterButtonCustomAction::create('createAccountPdf', 'Datenblatt erstellen')->setSuccessMessage('PDF Datenblatt mit Zugangsdaten wurde erstellt.'));
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the try but it still doesn't work. With your code I receive 'Call to a member function push() on a non-object ' and if I add '$fields = parent::getBetterButtonsActions();' or with updateBetterButtonsActions I receive 'Call to undefined method DataExtension::getBetterButtonsActions()'

Comment: Oops, my bad. We only have the variable $actions available (defined int the function), so try a $actions->push...